# PWA | When clicking to open appleid.apple.com, its redirects to the app store in iOS

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps, mobile-safari, inappbrowser, apple-id

I am facing a strange issue, this is related to Progressive Web Apps (PWA) apps on the iOS platform. So, when the user opens the link of the app in the Safari mobile browser and then clicks on https://appleid.apple.com then it's working fine but when the user adds the link on the home screen from Add to Home Screen from Safari menu options and launches the app from the home screen then clicks on https://appleid.apple.com then its redirects to AppStore.

Please checkout the screenshot also:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikV5Q.png)

I tried every possible solution but nothing seems to be working.

Things that doesn't work

Changing the scope in the manifest-file

- Using a href
- Using windows.open
- Using rel="noreferrer"
- Using target="_blank"
- Using schema

I want like that if the user clicks on the https://appleid.apple.com from the home screen app then it should open in InAppBrowser in iOS, this should not be redirected to AppStore